# IOS-SWIFT- Remote Notification to show in-app banner

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

Recently, I worked on a messaging app using APNs. When a remote notification was received, the delegate function application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler) will be called and I post some notification to the NotificationCenter, then the observer can append the new message to my local message array.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "com.rjt.Chao.messaging"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

This works fine but when I want to add in-app notification banner by writing the following:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
}
```

I can get in-app banner now but application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler) is not called and fails to post notification to NotificationCenter.

Why is it like this?  What's the best way to implement a instant messaging app with in-app notification banner?